# Content type disappear when cache is cleared

Tags: 7, nodes, caching

Lately, every time I clear the cache, my content types are systematically deleted. I use Drupal 7.36.

The main plugins I use are the following:

- Views 3.10
- Chaos Tools 1.7
- Entity API 1.6 and others.

When I'm on Drupal 7.34, I don't have this problem. Maybe I should update the 7.34 version to 7.35 then 7.36

Have you any idea ?

Comment: are you referring to custom, core or both kinds of content types?

Comment: Are you using Features module for that contents? You may be suffering this bug: https://www.drupal.org/node/2465159

Comment: Or have you ever used features? Tunic's bug can be triggered if you once used features but then removed it.

Comment: I'm referring to both kinds of content types.

Features is disabled.

Comment: Today I updated the core Drupal 7.34 to 7.35 , no problem with my content types after the cache is cleared. 

7.35 to 7.36 , my content types are removed even without emptying the cache.